# MVC 6 Ajax Call from view always pass null to Controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Im trying to send my Model-List to Method in Controller like this :

```
$("table#phonelist tr").each(function () {

        $this = $(this)
        var phonetype = $this.find("#phonetupeselect option:selected").val();
        var phonenumber = $this.find("#phonenumber").val();
        var obj = new Object();
        if (phonetype !== undefined && phonenumber !== undefined && phonenumber !== "")
        {
            obj.ID = 0;
            obj.Number = phonenumber;
            obj.PhoneTypeId = phonetype;
            phonelist.push(obj);
        }
    });

    var emps = JSON.stringify({ 'phonelist': phonelist });
    $.ajax({
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/Controller1/AddPhone",
        data: emps ,
        success: function (result) {
            submit();
        },
    });
```

Output of Ajax in Fiddler :

```
{"phonelist":[{"ID":0,"Number":"111111","PhoneTypeId":"10"},{"ID":0,"Number":"222222","PhoneTypeId":"11"},{"ID":0,"Number":"333333","PhoneTypeId":"12"}]}
```

And method in Controller1 :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void AddPhone(List<PhoneViewModel> phonelist)
    {
     //empty atm
    }
```

PhoneViewModel model :

```
public class PhoneViewModel
    {

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public string PhoneTypeId { get; set; }
    }
```

cant find why phonelist is always null in controller method.

[image]

Comment: `data: emps,` (not `data: { 'phonelist': emps },`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke sorry man, that was typo. edited my question.

Comment: Then that should work fine.

Comment: @StephenMuecke still nothing , and cant find a way to debug it. :(

Comment: Just tested your code and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slight changes in your code. This will solve.

```
 var emps = JSON.stringify({ 'phonelist': phonelist });
    var model =  { phonelist: JSON.parse(phonelist) };
        $.ajax({
            contentType: 'application/json',
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/Controller1/AddPhone",
            data: JSON.stringify(model),
            success: function (result) {
                submit();
            },
        });
```